# Copy Data Tables from Multiple Worksheets, Omitting #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a data table on the "Summary" sheet by pulling data from the same range of the other sheets in the work book. Some of these tables have entire rows that are #N/A. I do not want the #N/A rows copied to the master sheet, and I do not want any gaps in the assembled table. The code below, copies everything and does not have any gap rows. How can I eliminate the #N/A rows?

```
Sub Summary()

Dim wkstDst As Worksheet
Dim wkstSrc As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range

Set wkstDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
wkstDst.Select

For Each wkstSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If wkstSrc.Name <> "Summary" Then
        With wkstSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(11, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 5)                
            rngSrc.Copy Destination:=wkstDst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
        End With
    End If
Next wkstSrc

End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to loop on each row of each worksheet and check all* the cells in the row to see if they contain valid data. Then only copy the rows without `#N/A`.   *"all" in this case is however many columns you care about for that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter and select just the visible rows before you do the copy/paste operation.

The modified code assumes filtering will be OK if you just check the first column of your table, so:

```
        With wkstSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(11, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 5)
            With rngSrc
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                    Destination:=wkstDst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have copied everything in to the Summary sheet, then do the following code. It should be close. I just keyed it in because unfortunately I don't have any more time right now. Good luck! Post back if you need some more help.

If you have lots of completely NA rows then it might make more sense to use this code in the individual sheets instead of after you have done all of your consolidation.

```
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lEndRow As Long, lEndCol As Long
Dim bValidCellFound As Boolean
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    lEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A or some other applicable Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lEndCol = .Cells(1 or some other Applicable Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For lRow = lEndRow To 1 Step -1
        bValidCellFound = False
        For lCol = 1 To lEndCol
            If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Cells(lRow, lCol) Then
                bValidCellFound = True
                Exit For
            EndIf
        Next
        If Not bValidCellFound Then
            ' I like to use call so that even subs take parentheses around the arguments.
            Call .Rows(lRow).Delete(Shift:=xlUp);
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lEndRow As Long, lEndCol As Long
Dim bValidCellFound As Boolean
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    lEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lEndCol = .Cells(200, "F").End(xlToLeft).Column

    For lRow = lEndRow To 1 Step -1
        bValidCellFound = False
        For lCol = 1 To lEndCol
            If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Cells(lRow, lCol)) Then
                bValidCellFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not bValidCellFound Then
            Call .Rows(lRow).Delete(Shift:=xlUp)
        End If
    Next
End With
```